# IDE for redmine/rails and configuring the project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am actually developing a plugin for redmine, Currently using netbeans 6.9
(OS: Linux)

But the problem i am facing is to get the changes i have manually restart the redmine server from console.

Is there a better IDE/ Configurations? Any one who has worked in same area, can provide some guidance?

Also i would like to know how to run Redmine server in development mode, so that it eases the development process.

Any suggestions/Directions would be helpful, appreciated.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

---

Well i can recommend you using RubyMine as an IDE from my personal experience. It is an excellent IDE with a lot of new features.
you can download it for free from the link given below

http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/